# Does Hibernate HQL Support Regular expression pattern matching?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I was testing different ways of data retrieval from my database (MySQL) using Hibernate. And I get to know that it is possible to use `LIKE` in HQL just like we do it in SQL. But when I tried `REGEXP` I got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: REGEXP near line 1, column 54 [from com.jithin.hibernate.entity.Student where fname REGEXP '@gmail.com$']
```

I have also tried the different forms like `RLIKE` and `REGEXP_LIKE`. But the error is same. So why does the `LIKE` operator is supported by HQL and why not `REGEXP`? Is there anyway to achieve it?

The code I used is as follows

```
session.beginTransaction();
List<Student> students = session.createQuery("from Student where email REGEXP 'gmnail.com$'"),getResultList();
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Hello, please edit your question and replace the screenshot with actual code snippet.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator is declared in the base hibernate abstract [Dialect](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.java#L1840) class. This is how hibernate know about it.

You can extend your hibernate dialect for example in the following way:

```java
public class YourDialect extends MySQL8Dialect {

   public YourDialect(){
      registerFunction(
          "REGEXP_LIKE",
           new StandardSQLFunction( "REGEXP_LIKE", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER )
      );
   }
}
```

Then declare this dialect in your hibernate config and then you will be able to use the `REGEXP_LIKE` function in hql queries.